# Delete a row from a class in Parse - In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I'm trying to make some voting buttons for my film app.

I use Parse, and I've created a new class called `Votes_Up`. In this class their are 2 columns: `User_Voting` and `Film_VotedFor`.

My code below is actioned when the button is pressed. It takes the currentUser and the film object that the button has been pressed against, and adds them to Parse. My database looks like this:

[image]

**What I need**

so they way it currently works, if the user presses the vote button, it adds the info to the DB and adds 1 to the count. When the user presses it again, it just updates the count by taking 1 away.

I would also want to remove the row it would have added to the database, By the User that voted for it.  How can I do this??

**My code:**

```
@IBAction func upVoteButton(sender: UIButton) {

    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)

    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

        if userPressedUpButton == false {

            userPressedUpButton = true

            let voteUp = PFObject(className: "Votes_Up")
            voteUp["User_Voting"] = PFUser.currentUser()
            voteUp["Film_VotedFor"] = object!

            object!.incrementKey("UpVoteCount")
            object!.saveInBackground()

            voteUp.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) in

                if success == true {

                    // Object(s) was/were successfully saved

                } else if error != nil {

                    // Display an alert to the user

                } else {

                    // Display an alert to the user - something went wrong

                }

            })

        } else {

            userPressedUpButton = false

           // I need to removed the row from the class here that was added, as the user has retracted their vote!

            object!.incrementKey("UpVoteCount", byAmount: -1)
            object!.saveInBackground()

        }

    } else {

        // No user is logged in so they can't vote
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Votes_LoginPopup", sender: self)

    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Votes_Up")
    query.whereKey("User_Voting", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser())
    query.limit = 1
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (votesUp: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = votesUp as? [PFObject] {
                var firstObject = objects[0]
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    // do delete here
                    firstObject.deleteEventually();
                })

            }
        }
    }
```

or this:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Votes_Up")
query.whereKey("User_Voting", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    for object in objects {
        object.deleteEventually()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have read this, but it doesn't translate to what i'm actually trying to do. I have attempted what they recommend but I can't get my result.

Comment: I thought you want to delete the row? this is how you do it...by calling delete...unless you're trying to do something else

Comment: I want to delete a row that was made by the user that added it. The link you've sent doesn't show me how to do that, and nor is it written in Swift.

Comment: what is the relationship between user and vote_Up object? I think you need to fetch your vote_up object where the User_Voting == currentUser, then delete that row. As for the language, I think you can convert it to swift, right?